# ReferenceError: process is not defined, Node, Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I'm trying to call a Heroku environment variable in a Node/Express app.

I set the env variable in Heroku using

```
heroku config:set GITHUB_TOKEN=<my github api token without quotation marks>
```

It is set correctly (I checked by running heroku config)

gitUserSearchController.js:

```
githubUserSearch.controller('GitUserSearchController', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  var self = this;

  var searchResource = $resource('https://api.github.com/search/users/');
  var githubToken=process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN;

  self.doSearch = function() {
    self.searchResult = searchResource.get(
      { q: self.searchTerm, access_token: githubToken }
    );
  };
}]);
```

I get a console error readout of "Reference error: process is not defined" from line 5.

Comment: Are you sure it's not an angular client-side app? It looks that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't see local environment variables from the client side of a web app. This is desired behavior, of course, because otherwise you'd have just shared your github token with the world!

`process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN` will work within node.js, but it won't work in the user's browser (that looks like an Angular controller to be run in the browser, correct?)

Comment: Long time ago, but yes it was an Angular controller.